# unable to run command ~$ vue add unit-mocha in vue cli 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, mocha-webpack

I want to add mocha as a unit testing plugin to my already created vue project, which was built using CLI 3 i.e. vue create myProj

this is for vue CLI 3.0.0+, in which my current project is running

BELOW IS THE ERROR when i run command

~$ vue add unit-mocha

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli-plugin-unit-mocha - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'vue-cli-plugin-unit-mocha@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Piktorlabs\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-04T10_03_45_315Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error -D vue-cli-plugin-unit-mocha
```

hence as per the NPM documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha

it says to run command ~$ vue add unit-mocha
to add mocha unit testing plugin in an already created project, but i get a 404 error in the CLI saying that the npm directory does not exist

Comment: The error is correct, that resource does not exists, suggest you follow the advice in the error and contact the developers.

Comment: My issue was resolved in the Vue GitHub forum

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I did not update the Vue cli to the latest version, the cli version was 2.6.0...once I updated it to 4.0 0, the issue was resolved